# Can't delete a record in a Custom Object using a certain profile

Tags: custom-object, profile, sharing, delete, org-wide-defaults

My custom object Project Team has a Public Read/Write OWD. The profile Regional Manager has a Modify all access to the Project Team custom object. When trying to login as the Regional Manager, I cannot delete a record in that object. Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When selected 'Modify All' it means that we have overridden the sharing settings and security. If Modify All is selected, then obviously Delete permission is there, as said [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=What-does-the-Modify-All-Data-perm-actually-do-1326847422250&language=en_US&type=1).

I would suggest you retry and let us know if you are still stuck.